# Update record with IsActive

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I am trying to build a dimension table which will identify current and historical data, by using the fields 'IsActive' and 'EffectiveDate'.

IsActive of 1 = Active.

EffectiveDate = Date the record was ingested.

Scenario: I have an existing record with the current view of the employee, however if any information about the employee changes, instead of updating the existing record, I would like to create a new line item with the updated record becoming active and the previous record becoming inactive.

| ID | Name | Surname | Age | IsActive | EffectiveDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe | 54 | 1 | 2021-01-01 |

When a change to the employee data is done, I would like to update the table as follows:

| ID | Name | Surname | Age | IsActive | EffectiveDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe | 54 | 0 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2 | John | Doe | 64 | 1 | 2021-06-25 |

I am using the combination of 'Name', 'Surname', and 'Age' to identify unique records. The reason I am using these three fields is because there is no other information provided to uniquely identify an employee.

I would really appreciate any assistance.

Comment: It sounds like you are reinventing Temporal Tables, a feature that already exists? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/temporal-tables

Comment: Your schema is flawed, using Name and Age is destined to fail as people can change names and their age is an ever changing number, you need to introduce some sort of surrogate key to identify records with a proper unique key. Think about creating a good design first and a lot of the problems will disappear with it, your design is very error prone and no amount of code can stop it from going bad.

Comment: @M.Ali thank you for the comment. I am aware that the design is flawed. However, my hand is forced due to what has been given. Is there any way that I could make something work with what I have?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I will investigate temporal tables.

Comment: To make a historical table the way you have it in mind, I recommend you have a log table where you leave your history and another where you have the current one, and the record in the history can be done by means of a trigger, but you have to Put a primary key (identity) so that you do not have problems, since using the first and last name is not recommended, it is bad practice !.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this yourself, but I would give [Temporal Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/temporal-tables) a try first, this is pretty much exactly what they were designed for. You just need to learn slightly different query syntax to find the rows that were "active" at a point in time or during a range.

In the meantime I can share a very simple example of how to do this yourself, but I agree with the comment that Name + Surname + Age is a terrible primary key, because all three of those could change for any given employee (and the age absolutely will change - this is why we usually store Birthdate instead). Why don't we *pretend* that we assign each employee, somewhere, a unique but meaningless ID (the kind of thing that would go on their access badge or the data in the HR database) just to keep the example simple.

Let's say your table is:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.EmployeeHistoryStuff
(
  ID            bigint       NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  EmployeeID    int, 
  Name          nvarchar(50), 
  Surname       nvarchar(50),
  Age           tinyint,
  IsActive      bit          NOT NULL DEFAULT (1),
  EffectiveDate datetime2(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT sysutcdatetime()
);
```

And we can add a few sample rows:

```
INSERT dbo.EmployeeHistoryStuff(EmployeeID, Name, Surname, Age) 
VALUES(1, N'Aaron', N'Bertrand', 29),
      (2, N'Teemu', N'Selanne',  31),
      (3, N'Bobby', N'Orr',      62),
      (4, N'Wayne', N'Gretzky',  55);
```

Now we can create a trigger that intercepts any updates any previous rows to `IsActive = 1` and inserts a new row:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.InsteadOfEmployeeHistoryStuff
ON dbo.EmployeeHistoryStuff
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @now datetime2(0) = sysutcdatetime();
  
  UPDATE old SET IsActive = 0
    FROM inserted AS i
    INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeeHistoryStuff AS old
    ON i.EmployeeID = old.EmployeeID
    WHERE old.IsActive = 1;
  
  INSERT dbo.EmployeeHistoryStuff(EmployeeID, Name, Surname, Age, EffectiveDate)
    SELECT EmployeeID, Name, Surname, Age, DATEADD(SECOND, 1, @now)
      FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

Now, if we perform an update because some employees had a birthday:

```
 UPDATE dbo.EmployeeHistoryStuff SET Age += 1 WHERE EmployeeID IN (1,2);
```

> | ID | EmployeeID | Name | Surname | Age | IsActive | EffectiveDate |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | Aaron | Bertrand | 29 | False | 2021-10-22 13:37:24 |
> | 2 | 2 | Teemu | Selanne | 31 | False | 2021-10-22 13:37:24 |
> | 3 | 3 | Bobby | Orr | 62 | True | 2021-10-22 13:37:24 |
> | 4 | 4 | Wayne | Gretzky | 55 | True | 2021-10-22 13:37:24 |
> | 5 | 1 | Aaron | Bertrand | 30 | True | 2021-10-22 13:37:30 |
> | 6 | 2 | Teemu | Selanne | 32 | True | 2021-10-22 13:37:30 |

Then Wayne wants to get out of the limelight:

```
 UPDATE dbo.EmployeeHistoryStuff SET Surname = N'Schmetzky' WHERE EmployeeID = 4;
```

> | ID | EmployeeID | Name | Surname | Age | IsActive | EffectiveDate |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | Aaron | Bertrand | 29 | False | 2021-10-22 13:37:24 |
> | 2 | 2 | Teemu | Selanne | 31 | False | 2021-10-22 13:37:24 |
> | 3 | 3 | Bobby | Orr | 62 | True | 2021-10-22 13:37:24 |
> | 4 | 4 | Wayne | Gretzky | 55 | False | 2021-10-22 13:37:24 |
> | 5 | 1 | Aaron | Bertrand | 30 | True | 2021-10-22 13:37:30 |
> | 6 | 2 | Teemu | Selanne | 32 | True | 2021-10-22 13:37:30 |
> | 7 | 4 | Wayne | Schmetzky | 55 | True | 2021-10-22 13:37:35 |

Then Wayne changes his mind:

```
UPDATE dbo.EmployeeHistoryStuff SET Surname = N'Gretzky' WHERE EmployeeID = 4;
```

> | ID | EmployeeID | Name | Surname | Age | IsActive | EffectiveDate |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | Aaron | Bertrand | 29 | False | 2021-10-22 13:37:24 |
> | 2 | 2 | Teemu | Selanne | 31 | False | 2021-10-22 13:37:24 |
> | 3 | 3 | Bobby | Orr | 62 | True | 2021-10-22 13:37:24 |
> | 4 | 4 | Wayne | Gretzky | 55 | False | 2021-10-22 13:37:24 |
> | 5 | 1 | Aaron | Bertrand | 30 | True | 2021-10-22 13:37:30 |
> | 6 | 2 | Teemu | Selanne | 32 | True | 2021-10-22 13:37:30 |
> | 7 | 4 | Wayne | Schmetzky | 55 | False | 2021-10-22 13:37:35 |
> | 8 | 4 | Wayne | Gretzky | 55 | True | 2021-10-22 13:37:40 |
> | 9 | 4 | Wayne | Gretzky | 55 | True | 2021-10-22 13:37:40 |

My timings are a bit off here, I'll come back and fix in a bit.

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e60ee03927a45b2275ce53ceb855fb5c)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Merge** statement as one of the options, to update records in Target table (dim) when matched with Source table (raw table) based on condition.

Here to update the existing record you can’t use ‘Age’ column to define uniqueness in your combination, as your new dataset has the change of data in ‘Age’ column.

Below are my repro details:

1. Existing dimension employee data:

[image]

2. Source data:

[image]

3. Code:

   ```
    Create procedure sp_employee
    AS   

    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    BEGIN

   --update Active flag of existing data

    MERGE dim_employee AS Target
    USING employee_data AS Source
    ON Source.Name = Target.Name
    and Source.Surname = Target.Surname
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    Target.IsActive = 0;

   --Insert new data (assuming the table has only changed data set)
    Insert into dim_employee
    select Name, Surname, Age, IsActive, EffectiveDate from employee_data;

   End
   GO
   ```
4. If you have old records in the source table along with the new change set, you can use the below code to insert only the change dataset.

   ```
    Insert into dim_employee
    select Name, Surname, Age, IsActive, EffectiveDate from employee_data
    except
    select distinct a.Name, a.Surname, a.Age, a.IsActive, a.EffectiveDate from employee_data a
    inner join dim_employee b on a.Name = b.Name and a.Surname = b.Surname and a.Age = b.Age;
   ```
5. Execute stored procedure

   ```
    Exec sp_employee;
   ```
6. After executing stored procedure: Here IsActive column data for ‘John Doe’ got updated to 0 and a new record for ‘John Doe’ got inserted from employee_data table.

[image]

Comment: Nah. I really wouldn't use `MERGE` for this, especially when _you're really only running an `UPDATE`_. https://sqlblog.org/merge

Comment: Also your procedure assumes people can't update the table directly - we don't always have the ability to force all updates to go through a stored procedure.